# Zoom in & zoom out an iframe with PDF by clicking zoom buttons with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, iframe, zooming

I'm trying to zoom in and out of an iFrame with a PDF using two buttons.
The problem is that the zoom in/out applies only to the area around the PDF, and the PDF remains intact.

The one thing i am not getting is: There is three types of zoom on my page.

1. The zoom in/out using my buttons, that does apply to something because i can see the element changing width with clientWidth function.
2. If i leave my mouse right at the PDF and use my mouse wheel UP/DOWN, the zoom in/out works PERFECTLY - It does zoom in/out the PDF.
3. The browser zoom - If i leave my mouse outside the PDF region, it does the browser zoom (110%, etc. Chrome zoom...)

Below is my HTML and my JS.
No CSS used for this.

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>O que é HTML?</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./O que é HTML.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="titulo">
      <h1>PDF sem opção de download - HTML</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="pdfViewer">
      <iframe
        src="./pdfs/Apostila HTML.pdf#toolbar=0&navpanes=0&statusbar=0&messages=0"
        width="100%"
        height="500px"
      >
      </iframe>
    </div>
    <div id="zoom">
      <button type="button" onclick="maisZoom()">Aumentar zoom</button>
      <button type="button" onclick="menosZoom()">Diminuir zoom</button>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function maisZoom() {
    var myPDF = document.getElementById("pdfViewer");
    var zoomAtual = myPDF.clientWidth;
    if (zoomAtual == 2500) return false;
    else {
        myPDF.style.width = (zoomAtual + 100) + "px";
    }
  }
  
  function menosZoom() {
    var myPDF = document.getElementById("pdfViewer");
    var zoomAtual = myPDF.clientWidth;
    if (zoomAtual == 100) return false;
    else {
        myPDF.style.width = (zoomAtual - 100) + "px";
    }
  }
```

Below is a GIF showing exactly what i said above.
Gif explained:

1. First zoom using buttons.
2. Second zoom using mouse wheel with my mouse on the PDF region.
3. Third zoom using mouse wheel with my mouse outside PDF region, which does the browser zoom.

I want to replicate the second zoom - Zoom in/out of the PDF using the buttons.

[image: Zoom GIF]

Any help is appreciate it!
Thank you.

Comment: Oh... So no solutions for this then? No way to replicate mouse wheel scrool using JavaScript?

Comment: I will try to emulate a mouse scroll then, to see if it works... Thank you for the idea. The #zoom wouldnt really work since i need the zoom to be on-demand using those two buttons. :/ And unfortunattelly i can not convert this PDF to a image (Like png...). I will keep trying!